# self reference value

Tags: scala

I encountered a value initialization problem:

```
class Top 

class X(val v : Top) extends Top 
class Y extends Top
```

X is a class constructed using other Top typed object, such as X or Y. Which means it may be constructed using itself. For example,

```
val x = new X(x)
```

The compiler will work, but when I access the v field, I got null returned.

```
scala> x.v 
res9: Top = null
```

I tried lazy initialization and by-name parameter, getting the same result. My Scala version is 2.9.1. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5):

Lung,

how did your code with lazy and call-by-name look like? It works for me like this:

```
class Top
class X(_v: => Top) extends Top {
  lazy val v = _v
}

scala> lazy val x: X = new X(x)
x: X = <lazy>

scala> x.v
res3: Top = X@422d15ad
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The combination of by-name parameter and lazy field work in this example perfectly. But what I really encountered is if I have to use by-name parameter, I need repeated by-name parameters.

for example,

class X(val v : =>Top*) extends Top

I tried this, but it didn't support by scala now. Do you have any better solution ?

Regards,
Chin-Lung Chang

Comment: I think you can only achieve this by using either functions (`class X(v: (() => Top)*)` or build a lazy wrapper around `Top`. Both is not very clean. Why do you need to pass a reference to the `Top` itself anyway?

Comment: Some data are naturally recursive. For example, the definition of XML element in DTD could be recursively defined. ex. <!ELEMENT A (A|Empty)>. Actually I'm developing a XML DTD validator/extractor, that's why I need recursive value here. By the way, I got around this problem by using var instead val field that I can construct value first then insert a content model that refer to itself into the var field.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed unfortunate, and also happens in Scala 2.9.2; you need to add the type there, though, so it's `val x: X = new X(x)`. I think the compiler should clearly reject this as it can't succeed with eager argument `v`.

I don't know what your exact scenario is, but it seems to be a data structure. Maybe an approach like the following works for you

```
trait Top
trait X extends Top { def v: Top }

object TopLoop extends X { def v: Top = this }
class Y( x: X ) extends Top { def v: Top = x }
```

If you want to use pattern matching, you can furthermore add `sealed` to the traits and `case` to the object and class.